# Fancybox 2 visible navigation arrows

Tags: jquery, navigation, fancybox, image-gallery

Is it possible with Fancybox 2.0 to always keep the image gallery navigation arrows visible? Rather than just visible on hover.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

For fancybox v2.x you may use these CSS inline declarations (after you have linked to the jquery.fancybox.css file):

```
<style type="text/css">
 .fancybox-next span {
  left: auto;
  right: 20px;
 }
 .fancybox-prev span {
  left: 20px;
 }
</style>
```

**UPDATE** (July 12, 2012) : Since Fancybox v2.0.6+ just need to add this css declaration instead

```
.fancybox-nav span {
 visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
#fancybox-left-ico {
    left: 10px !important;
}
#fancybox-right-ico {
    left: auto !important;
    right: 10px !important;
}
```